# GWT table with vertically aligned columns, celltree in first column

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

I'm wondering how well I can use GWT (or smart GWT) to build something like:

[image: table to build]

where I have:

1. A celltree in the first column that has a scrollbar at the bottom.
2. for each element in the tree, there are columnns 2 and 3 as shown, and columns 2 and 3 stay vertically lined up with the top.

This means if the celltree is deeply nested, the user would have to scroll it at the bottom, which is fine.   I need the vertical columns to stay aligned.

Comment: I guess you are looking for tree grid. Google for treegrid and smartgwt suffix. There are many options available

Answer (score 0):

Put a CellTree and a DataGrid side by side in a HorizontalPanel or LayoutPanel. Add a selection handler to a tree which refreshes the content of a DataGrid. If you set the same row height in a DataGrid as the height of a TreeItem, and prevent both from wrapping, they would align nicely.

You can even add a background to your CellTree items to match the DataGrid even/odd row backgrounds, but you will have to do it in code after every selection event on a non-leaf item in a CellTree.

Comment: Thank you Andrei, I'm going to try that later today and see if I can get it to work.   May I ask, do you use GWT or smart GWT (free license with enhanced widgets)?  Also, I forgot to say the celltree should be editable, but I assume this is no problem?

Comment: I use pure GWT. Editable cells should make no difference.

Comment: Andrei, I'm having a terrible time getting GWT Designer working/installed -- should I not use it anymore?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26264300/creating-eclipse-gwt-designer-project

Comment: I never used it. I find it much faster to write code manually, especially using UiBinder.