# How to create Eclipse GWT Designer Project, something is off?

Tags: gwt, eclipse-plugin, windowbuilder

After downloading the latest Eclipse (Luna 4.4.1), I installed the GWT / GWT designer plugin.

I concluded I that I am missing WindowsBuilderPro, and so I installed it via Eclipse Help->Install New Software.

Now I want to create a new GTW Designer project, and get the following choices, which I think are wrong:

[image]

Tutorials, perhaps older, show the following project choice:

[image]

Is my installation messed up?  I reversed the installation order, and nothing changed.

Is GWT Designer out of date, should I no longer be using it?

---

I'm a bit more confused based on your answer (Phil).   I found this presentation:

[The Future of GWT, 2013 Report](https://vaadin.com/documents/10187/42fbbec4-51c8-426b-8aa8-fe46129353a3)

and it shows:

[image]

Does GWT Designer still exist (2014) as something separate from UI Binder (I don't really want to do any HTML)?

If not, do I need the WindowBuilder plugin for UIBinder?

Comment: You can use UiBinder without GWT designer: when you just use XML Source and write xml by hand. The GWT Designer is just a tool to design graphically in a kind of wysiwyg, and on the background it add code in the java and the ui.xml files.

Answer (score 0):

You don't directly create a GWT Designer project. Create a "Web application project" as displayed in your first screenshot. Then create a new "UiBinder":
[image]

It will create two files: one java file and one .ui.xml file.
When you will open the .ui.xml file, you will have two tabs at the bottom of the window: one for the code, and one for the graphic designer:
[image]

Comment: Hi Phil, thanks for your answer. I'm going to try what you said. Can you please comment per updates I show in the question.  Is WindowBuilder still needed?

Comment: I installed the Google Web TookKit plugin -- see link above.  When I search on "ui" as you do in the wizard, I don't get any results back.

Comment: I don't know why you don't see UiBinder in the wizard. I also use Eclipse Luna, and I have installed the plugin from 
https://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.4